Thread-safety: Using many ifstream objects to read a file in parallel
Is it cross-platform safe to use multiple ifstream objects in parallel to read a single file?
It's probably a bottleneck and the required seekg won't be able to handle much, but I can't find any explicit information on the thread safety of the operation.

As far as C++ is concerned you just have multiple ifstream objects...

multiple threads are not universal cure for performance problems. When IO is main bottleneck it is usually result of hardware limitation. Adding more ifstreams for each thread will most probably lead to performance degradation since it will not improve use of hardware. So before jumping on multiple threads firs make sure what is the root cause of performance issue - do program profiling.

ifstream is not thread-safe in a sense that you can access the same ifstream object from multiple threads. But different ifstream objects can be used at the same time in different threads, and on a multi-threaded OS it's absolutlely fine to open the same file multiple times for reading from different processes or from multiple threads within the same process. Writing to a file can be more problematic, though. Also remember that another process might modify the file you are reading, if you are not locking properly. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216643

There is no cross-platform guarantee that you can even open the same file multiple times.

@MarekR I'm debugging existing code and want to pin point whether this is a/the problem. So before I start refactoring the universe, I want to confirm whether my apprehension is valid. Want to chime in ?

@n.m.couldbeanAI I'm pretty sure this is true, but is there any reference/guide that would make my case solid? I'm trying to support the idea that a piece of code is responsible for some read file issues and so far I don't have much more than "hey this looks fishy"

If the file is on "spinning rust" (hard disk not SSD) then multiple ifstreams can cause excessive seeking and  significantly slow down reading the file.

"...a piece of code is responsible for some read file issues ..." use a profiler.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Can you name a platform supporting multi-threading, but not opening the same file more than once?

This is very bad thing that after taking over legacy code your first thought is adding threads to it. Like wrote start from profiling, many developers do not use this tool and are scared to try it, but with a little bit of: trying, reading and training; you will get great results.

@Jens in the SO topic you linked, I see an answer from a 100K+ user saying "Having two openings of the same file might cause an inconsistent view between the files, depending on the underlying OS." . The problem is that on every discussion/forum there's these two opposite opinions: "yes you can" / "no you cannot even open". Is there a textbook or Windows/Linux manual reference where a definitive answer can be given? So far, even there mere volume of disagreements makes the code look fishy to me

@MarekR I think you are trolling. I am not adding threads, threads are there. I said already I'm debugging. If anything I'm looking for enough justification to remove the threads in that part. If you intend to be helpful please pay some attention, if you're just having fun .. well I can't stop you

@NikosAthanasiou I never experienced inconsistent views when just reading from a file (and making sure other processes also don't modify that file). When reading and writing the same file, of course there can be inconsistent views.

@NikosAthanasiou consult the docs for the OS of how it is handling file opening (like CreateFile in Windows, for example). If it doesn't mention anything of the like people claiming in generic comments you are safe to ignore those comments unless some concrete facts are specified. Anyway, who cares if OS Doors 1.78 handles files in some weird way if you don't use that OS. So your best bet is the API docs for the OSs you use.

@Jens A guarantee if X is not absence of evidence for non-X.

Every time that a thread switches, the hard drive or SSD has to perform overhead to reposition the "read pointer".  This takes time.  The most efficient method to read is to keep the data stream flowing, from hard drive to memory.  Reduce the overhead by increasing the transaction size.  For example, one read of 1024 bytes is more efficient than 1024 reads of 1 byte.  Remember that the hard drive is a serial device; one bit is read at a time.  Some universities have played with the idea of connecting 8 hard drives in order to read and write one byte in parallel.
