# What should I use instead of std::ostrstream?

Tags: c++, stream, deprecated

I like to use [`std::ostrstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ostrstream) to format text but not print it to stdout but instead write it into an `std::string` (by accessing the `std::ostrstream::str()` member). Apparently this is *deprecated* now. So, how am I supposed to write formatted objects to a string, with the same convenience as when writing to a stream?

Comment: It's been deprecated for the past 14 years, where've you been?  :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Well, let's say I realised it only some short time ago. Obviously I didn't pay enough attention :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream). Similarly, instead of `std::istrstream` you should use `std::istringstream`. You need to include the `<sstream>` header for these classes.

You could also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820221/why-was-stdstrstream-deprecated) which explains why `strstream` was deprecated.

Comment: I am baffled by the downvote! Does anyone see something wrong in there?

Comment: You got an upvote from me, but I would guess the downvote was because you linked to cplusplus.com, which is terrible and full of bad style and some outright errors.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I am aware that cplusplus.com sucks. I try to avoid it myself always. Do you know a reliable website I can include? The problem is that searched on google **always** brings that website up first. When you go further down, you see MSDN (which I wouldn't even consider for an instance) and then you are out of reference sites and into Q&A sites such as stackoverflow.

Comment: I used to use the dinkumware manuals but last time I checked they'd gone.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, you see? We need a good reference online, but I can't find any.

Comment: I'm under the impression that cppreference.com (which I linked to in the OP) is better than cplusplus.com but I've nothing to back that up, unfortunately.

Comment: @bitmask, I changed the link to cppreference.com. I guess good or bad, it can't be as bad as cplusplus.com

Answer (score 3):

As others have already said, `std::ostringstream` is the replacement.

It's more convenient (and safer) than `std::ostrstream` because it manages all memory automatically so you don't need to call `freeze(false)` to ensure the memory gets freed when you're finished with it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).  Also, see [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

`std::stringstream` supports both `<<` and `>>`.  `std::ostringstream` only supports `<<`, and `std::istringstream` only supports `>>`.  Often I find it convenient to be able to use both operators.

Comment: He "should" in any case? What if he only needs input or only output? In that case I advice against too general solutions.

Answer (score 1):

With C++20 you can use [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/). Then you can do things like:

```
int a = 1;
std::string b("foo");
std::string s = boost::str(
    boost::format("some text, some vars=%1%, %2%, %1%") % a % b % a);
```

Then `s` would contain `"some text, some vars=1, foo, 1"`.

This is, in my opinion, more convenient in some cases than using operator `<<`.

As a reference, I also include the [format specification](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#printf_directives).

Comment: You want to stop using '%d' and other type specific stuff as this will lead to the same problems as sprintf(). Prefer the index specific identifiers '%1'.

Comment: @LokiAstari thanks for that! I didn't know about it. I'll update my answer accordingly. But what if you just want to show floating point numbers with two decimals? Is there any other way than using `%.02f`?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#printf_directives "%1$.02f"