# No exception throw after open a file stream with non-exist files?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use

```
std::ifstream inStream;
inStream.open(file_name);
```

If `file_name` does not exists, no exception is thrown. How can I make sure to throw in this case? I am using C++11

Comment: [`std::ifstream::exceptions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You should probably post that as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: it works, but it cannot show which file does not exist; I can only show the failbits which is not important to me.

Comment: @Adam : Eh, you already have `file_name` in scope... What's the problem?

Comment: @ildjarn, when exception throw, I have no means to pass out file_name to exception message.

Comment: @Adam : Of course you do: catch the exception, and throw a different one including the filename.

Comment: You are right, I accepts the revised answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do so by setting the streams [exception mask](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions), before calling `open()`

```
std::ifstream inStream;
inStream.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
try {
    inStream.open(file_name);
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::ostringstream msg;
    msg << "Opening file '" << file_name 
        << "' failed, it either doesn't exist or is not accessible.";
    throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
}
```

By default none of the streams failure conditions leads to exceptions.

Comment: e.what() can only returns "unspecified iostream_category error" when file does not exist.

Comment: @AdamLee That's the best you can get AFAIK. There aren't that many possibilities besides non existing or non accessible files that the failbit is set by `open()`.

Comment: I edit one place, I need to use const std::exception& e rather than const & std::exception.

Comment: BTW, it seems that I have to std::ostrstream rather than ostringstream, please confirm.

Comment: @AdamLee THX, yes that was a typo. No `std::ostrstream` is obsolete. You need to `#include <sstream>`

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you mind to tell why the ostrstream is deprecated?

Comment: @AdamLee See here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820221/why-was-stdstrstream-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately setting `ios::failbit` in the exception mask before calling `ifstream::open`  leads to undesirable results:

1. The thrown [`std::ios_base::failure`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) does not state the reason for the I/O failure.
2. Reaching end-of-file also sets [`std::ios_base::failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) and hence, also throws an exception.

A possible better solution is to throw [`std::system_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) yourself:

```
std::ifstream in(file_name);

if (!in.is_open()) {
    throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), file_name);
}

std::string row;
while (std::getline(in, row)) {
    // . . . process the file . . .
}
if (in.bad()) {
    throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), file_name);
}
```

This will give proper error messages explaining the actual I/O error, for example " `test.file: No such file or directory`"